# Elbow method not giving a proper curve in python code

Tags: python, clustering, k-means

I am trying to determine how many clusters to use for my k-means clustering using different methods.
first i used the following code to calculate different metrics per cluster number and different kmeans parameters.

```
def calculate_metrics(X, labels, center_ ,true_labels=None,):
    # This assumes you have a function to calculate Dunn index
    # and that true_labels are provided for supervised metrics.
    metrics = {}
    if len(set(labels)) > 1:  # Checks if there is more than one cluster.
        metrics['silhouette'] = silhouette_score(X, labels)
        metrics['davies_bouldin'] = davies_bouldin_score(X, labels)
        metrics['calinski_harabasz'] = calinski_harabasz_score(X, labels)
        wss = calculate_wss(X_blob, result['labels'], center_)
        metrics['wss'] = wss  
        # metrics['dunn_index'] = dunn_index(X, labels)  # If you have an implementation for this.
    if true_labels is not None:
        metrics['NMI'] = normalized_mutual_info_score(true_labels, labels)
        metrics['ARI'] = adjusted_rand_score(true_labels, labels)
    return metrics
```

after that i tried to plot the metrics = ['silhouette', 'davies_bouldin', 'calinski_harabasz'] per different parameters.

i provided the three samples of my result although my results are so more,
but really i am so frustrated and need your help to find what should i do and how choice the best cluster number ?
[image] [image][image][image][image]